# Dispatch and catch when react redux thunk throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I understand that the best way in Redux/Toolkit is to handle errors from global store. But what if we need to execute one by one async function (with cheking errors on each step)?

For exapmle I have next Redux Thunk:

```
export const createAudio = createAsyncThunk<
  IAudioDetailData,
  IAudioCreateRequest,
  { rejectValue: IThunkCustomError }
>(
  "createAudio",
  async (audioTrack: IAudioCreateRequest, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        backendPaths.AUDIO_CREATE_URL(),
        JSON.stringify(audioTrack)
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err; // and I'v caught an backend error here 
      // return rejectWithValue(err.response?.data);
    }
  }
);
```

And somewhere in functional component when user submited form

```
const AudioCreate: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const handleCreateAudioTrack = async (values: IAudioFormValues) => {
    const createAudioRequest = {/* ... */};
    dispatch(createAudio(createAudioRequest))
    .then(result => {
    // some extra logic here... and I want to be shure there is no errors 
    // in this block
    })
    .then(() => dispatch(bindAudio())
    .catch(err => {
    // some logic here...
    });
  }
```

Why `.catch` block newer execute in Component? In case of error I have `result.paylod` with error in Component. What I do wrong?

However, Thunk always returns Payload on both cases success and failure and result may consist an error. Is there any way to realize that logic by another way?